# How to solve this error "The element type "head" must be terminated > by the matching end-tag "</head>"?

Tags: xml, xslt, parsing, xhtml

Why i'm getting this error

> Using
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
>   Exception
>   net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   element type "head" must be terminated
>   by the matching end-tag "". 
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   element type "head" must be terminated
>   by the matching end-tag "".

When i check this site http://visaraimpex.com/ in http://www.w3.org/2003/12/semantic-extractor.html

Comment: Can you post your head....er, i mean the `head` section of your HTML? :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that these two lines are part of the problem:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
```

Since this is XHTML (according to the DOCTYPE), you can either change "/>" to ">", or delete the "</script>".

This illustrates the kind of problems you have trying to extract stuff from real-world HTML. If that is what you are doing, maybe you should be using HTMLTidy or a similar "permissive" HTML parser rather than a strict parser.

Answer (score 0):

You close your <script> tags twice:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
```

Remove </script> and it should work.

Comment: Actually, a `<script>` tag must have a `</script>` closer. He should remove the / from the `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Trav - the DOCTYPE says XHTML, so a self-closing element should be fine.

Comment: HTML4-isms are evil. The self-closing version is more logical and much clearer.

Comment: The site *is* HTML4 though - at least to browsers. The self closing version will work for the semantic extractor, but not for the browser. Traveling Tech Guy's approach will work for both.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the head part of your HTML code with the following snippet:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Visara Impex</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="Visara Impex" content="">

    <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rb.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#menu li:nth-child(1)").addClass("current_page_item");
             $("#menu").css("background" , "url(images/nav/7.jpg) no-repeat left top");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```